# JS: preventDefault() for the link element <a>

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

When I click the nested image in the link the download popup appears at the top.
How to prevent the default behavior of the link element that is a parent of the image?

```
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="gallery__item">
        <a class="gallery__link" href="large-image.jpg">
          <img
            class="gallery__image"
            src="small-image.jpg"
            data-source="large-image.jpg"
            alt="Image description"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery__item">
        <a class="gallery__link" href="large-image.jpg">
          <img
            class="gallery__image"
            src="small-image.jpg"
            data-source="large-image.jpg"
            alt="Image description"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery__item">
        <a class="gallery__link" href="large-image.jpg">
          <img
            class="gallery__image"
            src="small-image.jpg"
            data-source="large-image.jpg"
            alt="Image description"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have try to stop propagation on the event.target -> img element. But this approach does not help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the purpose of your sample? why use a a tag for embed image ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the **preventDefault** function, such that when any of the links are clicked, we can prevent the default behavior, the download popup:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__link');

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // code here
  });
});
```

Alternatively you could also use a **return false** and you will get the same result.

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__link');

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // code here
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__image').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: Well, it should, I wonder why it doesn't work in this case. Is there a way to look at the live example?